# Return Select-String results with context from Invoke-Command (appear blank)

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, select-string

I'm trying to search log files on multiple servers using Invoke-Command and return the results with context but I'm having no success.

This is the command:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session {
  cd C:\LogDir\Log1
  sls -Pattern "ThingImLookingFor" -Path * -Context 1,5 
}
```

This returns a deserialized MatchInfo object with most info dropped.

How would I get results that look similar to running Select-String locally?

This is the result of running sls on an svg in my home dir with the same context settings as an example:

```
  horizontalBlock.svg:30:     id="base"
> horizontalBlock.svg:31:     pagecolor="#ffffff"
  horizontalBlock.svg:32:     bordercolor="#666666"
  horizontalBlock.svg:33:     borderopacity="1.0"
  horizontalBlock.svg:34:     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
  horizontalBlock.svg:35:     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
  horizontalBlock.svg:36:     inkscape:zoom="1.3289991"
```

Comment: Pipe `sls` to `Out-String`?

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Mind making it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe `sls` to `Out-String`:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session {
  cd C:\LogDir\Log1
  sls -Pattern "ThingImLookingFor" -Path * -Context 1,5 | Out-String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the custom format from the returned psobject appears blank.  Here's another workaround.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session {
  cd C:\LogDir\Log1
  select-string -Pattern "ThingImLookingFor" -Path * -Context 1,5 | select line
}
```

Or

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session {
  cd C:\LogDir\Log1
  select-string -Pattern "ThingImLookingFor" -Path * -Context 1,5 
} | select line, pscomputername
```